# swiftui: how can i disable a button and blur it after a condition is met?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I have a button in swiftUi. When the user presses that button the counter goes down from 5. Once the counter hits zero, the button will become disabled. I have got the code working till this point:

```
Button(action: {
    tnum = tnum - 1
}) {
    Text("Press Me!")
       .background(Color.purple) 
       .foregroundColor(.white)  
       .font(.title)             
       .padding() 
}
.disable(tnum <= 0)
```

I know how to blur a button. It would be something like `.blur(radius: 3, opaque: false)` but I only want this to be executed if the number is zero.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blur has no effect if radius is zero, so you can use

```
Button(action: {
    tnum = tnum - 1
}) {
    Text("Press Me!")
       .background(Color.purple) 
       .foregroundColor(.white)  
       .font(.title)             
       .padding() 
}
.blur(radius: tnum <= 0 ? 0 : 3, opaque: false)  // << here !!
.disable(tnum <= 0)
```

Comment: Thank you this works! The only change i had to make was `.blur(radius: tnum <= 0 ? 3 : 0, opaque: false)`